# Estimating the upper bound of prime count in the given range

Tags: arithmetic, analytic-number-theory

I need to estimate count of primes in the range $[n..m)$, where $n < m$, $n \in N$ and $m \in N$ and this estimation must always exceed the actual count of primes in the given range (i.e. be an upper bound).

The simple but ineffective solution would be just $m - n$, though it is fine when $m$ is close to $n$.

An accurate estimation would look as $[Li(m) - Li(n)]$ according to the Riemann formula for $\pi(x)$ but I believe I can't use it for upper bound.

So the questions is: how can I estimate this upper bound *effectively enough* (i.e. by using relatively simple calculations)?

If giving such an approximation is hard for $[n..m)$, may be some simple method exists for upper bound for the range $(1..m)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be the following.

The *exact* number of primes below a given number $x$ is given by the *prime counting function*, denoted as $\pi(x)$. For example, $\pi(10) = 4$ and $\pi(20) = 8$. However, to find $\pi(x)$ it is required to count the number of primes explicitly, which is cumbersome.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) informs me the following inequality:

$$\frac{x}{\ln x} < \pi(x) < 1.25506\frac{x}{\ln x}$$

Therefore the number of primes between $m$ and $n$ with $m > n$ is

$$\pi(m) - \pi(n) < 1.25506\left(\frac{m}{\ln m} - \frac{n}{\ln n}\right)$$

which is a much easier computation than, say, $\operatorname{Li}(x)$. This is not a rigorous argument but numerical evidence shows that the bound is fairly accurate.

**Caveat**: Be warned that this bound can fail if $m$ and $n$ are too close. You might want to experiment with different values of $m$ and $n$ and perhaps adjust the bound in one way or another if, say, $m - n$ is smaller than a threshold value.

**EDIT**: An alternative upper bound would be

$$1.25506\frac{m}{\ln m} - \frac{n}{\ln n}, \quad n > 17$$

which is safer to use, but much more inaccurate.

Comment: That is correct, but the one shown in my answer is more accurate, although my only supporting evidence is numerical. I have tested up to hundreds of thousands of primes, the bound would only fail if $m$ and $n$ are too close.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
A have only a small remark (mostly for myself, but it may help for someone else) - *effective* computation might be done by not directly calculating $ln m$, but using Taylor series for natural algorithm, e.g. as follows for $[1..n)$:
$\frac{63 * n}{500 * T(x)}$ - here T(x) - shorthand for Taylor series.